# Error in using Hadoop MapReduce in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

When I executed a [MapReduce program in Eclipse using Hadoop](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/mapreducetools), I got the below error.
It has to be some change in path, but I'm not able to figure it out.
Any idea?

```
16:35:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201001151609_0001_m_000006_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File C:/tmp/hadoop-Shwe/mapred/local/taskTracker/jobcache/job_201001151609_0001/attempt_201001151609_0001_m_000006_0/work/tmp does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.setupWorkDir(TaskRunner.java:519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:155)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the error message (`[...]6_0/work/tmp does not exist`), the first issues to check are:

- the right access under `c:\tmp`
- the initialization steps for [**this plugin**](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/mapreducetools) to run correctly: see [**this thread**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14202359&tstart=0#14202359)

Extract:

> If you installed it correctly, you should be able to start the MapReduce perspective and Map/Reduce view. Both are under `Window > Open Perspective` and `Show View` respectively.
>
> - Click the blue elephant on the upper right corner of the `Map/Reduce` view. It'll bring up a configuration window.
> - Type in any name for the the Location Name. I just called it localhost cluster.
> - Set the port numbers for Map/Reduce Master and DFS Master. Look in your conf/hadoop-`site.xml` for "`mapred.job.tracker`" and "`dfs.default.name`" respectively. If not in that file, then it is probably in `hadoop-default.xml` or `hadoop-env.xml`.
> - Click "`Advanced Parameters`" tab and set the "`mapred.job.tracker`" parameter. For some reason it doesn't automatically change when you change it in the "General" tab.
> - User name should be whoever owns hadoop. For me, it is just my login, others make a separate "hadoop" user for hadoop.
> - If you have done everything correctly, you should be able to click the triangles on the left to span the hierarchy view.

Answer (score 0):

check *core-site.xml* and *hdfs-site.xml* to see where is their address. both of them should be hdfs://localhost:[port] or file:///

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you are using cdh 5, cloudera quickstart VM then it is 8021 and 8020 respectively, unless you do additional config.